# I´m having this error when adding one line of code.... AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'login_manager'

Tags: python, flask

I have added this line of code to my login route:

```
profile_picture = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + current_user.profile_picture)
```

And now my program returns this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'login_manager'
```

This is my login route:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    session.clear()
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("login.html")
    if request.method == "POST":
        rows = User.query.filter_by(username=request.form.get("username")).first()
        if rows is None or not check_password_hash(rows.password, request.form.get("password")):
            flash('Usuario o contraseña incorrectos')
            return render_template("login.html")
        else:
            profile_picture = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + current_user.profile_picture)
            session["user_id"] = rows.user_id
            return render_template("profile.html", name=rows.name, genre=rows.genre, profile_picture=profile_picture)
```

I also have imported LoginManager package:

```
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_required, login_user, current_user
```

I cant notice why i'm getting this error. Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add:

```
login = LoginManager(app)
```

after your `app = Flask(__name__)` and furthermore I am then going on to:

```
login.login_view = 'login'
```

Please see https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins for background

Comment: That worked! Now im getting this error: Exception: Missing user_loader or request_loader.

Comment: Have you read https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins? It describes how you authenticate a login and will fix this if you can synergise it with your app